# Java web service SSL on AWS EC2?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2

I am using Dropwizard to develop my service that will eventually be hosted on an EC2 instance.

Currently Amazon Certificates can only be used for services like Elastic Beanstalk. 
You cannot download any of the certificate details to sign or roll your own key.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/acm/get-certificate.html

I tried using the java keytool to generate a keystore file for the public domain the service will be available at, however that gives a Certficate warning on the browser.

Is the solution to use Elastic beanstalk for Java services?

Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Like [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Java.html)?  If you're on EC2 you can use the AWS certs with a load balancer or you can use Apache in front of Tomcat/Wildfly/Glassfish and get a "normal" certificate.

Comment: @stdunbar no reason to require Apache in that scenario.

Comment: @MarkB - just a matter of preference and history.  It seems easier to setup SSL with Apache than with the java servers but you're 100% correct that it isn't required.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Dropwizard uses a Jetty container, however I am running this inside a docker container on EC2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the solution to use Elastic beanstalk for Java services?

That doesn't solve your issue in any way. That just gives you an EC2 instance with a Load Balancer. You could setup a Load Balancer yourself if you want one. Elastic Beanstalk doesn't provide special SSL certificate support beyond what you could do yourself.

> I tried using the java keytool to generate a keystore file for the
>   public domain the service will be available at, however that gives a
>   Certficate warning on the browser.

You generated a [self-signed certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-signed_certificate), which is going to show warnings in a browser. You need to obtain an SSL certificate from an actual certificate authority if you want to avoid the browser warnings.

If you don't want to use a Load Balancer or CloudFront along with an AWS ACM certificate, then you will need to procure a valid SSL certificate from some other certificate authority and install that directly on your EC2 instance. The most popular way to do this without incurring any cost is to use [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) certificates.

Comment: Thanks, so if I go loadbalancer way, I just use HTTP with the web service and the Load balancer handles TLS?

Comment: Yes, if you use a load balancer you just serve HTTP on the EC2 server and the load balancer handles the SSL/TLS termination. You can check the `x-forwarded-proto` header on the server side to see if the client is connected to the load balancer over HTTP or HTTPS. If you use an Application Load Balancer you will also get some nice things like web socket support and HTTP/2 support.